# Check if cell is a number in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

in the code below, I am working on doing numeric calculations on cells.  Sometimes though, one of the cells(say for example the"LosLimit") may contain a non-numeric value like "---".  How do I check if the cell is numeric or not.

If it is a number, then do calculation, else return value from "MeasValue"

```
Sub ReturnMarginal()

    'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWks As Worksheet
    Dim InterSectRange As Range
    Dim lowLimCol As Integer
    Dim hiLimCol As Integer
    Dim measCol As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each xWks In xWb.Sheets
        xRow = 1
        With xWks
           FindString = "LowLimit"
           If Not xWks.Rows(1).Find(FindString) Is Nothing Then
               .Cells(xRow, 16) = "Meas-LO"
               .Cells(xRow, 17) = "Meas-Hi"
               .Cells(xRow, 18) = "Min Value"
               .Cells(xRow, 19) = "Marginal"
               LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
               lowLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("LowLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
               hiLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("HighLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
               measLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("MeasValue", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
                .Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(" & .Cells(2, lowLimCol).Value2 & ")," & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address(False, False) & "-" & Cells(2, lowLimCol).Address(False, False) & "," & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address(False, False) & ")"


               .Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Formula = "=" & Cells(2, hiLimCol).Address(False, False) & "-" & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address(False, False)

               .Range("R2").Formula = "=min(P2,Q2)"
               .Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("R2:R" & LastRow)

               .Range("S2").Formula = "=IF(AND(R2>=-3, R2<=3), ""Marginal"", R2)"
               .Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("S2:S" & LastRow)

           End If

        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on
    Next xWks

End Sub
```

Comment: Google returns `1,290,000` results by entering just the title.

Comment: @A.S.H, I'm sorry, but I put in the code pre test...i.e. where my thought process was going... and that was not very far!  I have updated the code with what I had actually tried but it only returns the "MeasValue".  Am I using the 'isNumeric' incorrectly?  Thanks

Comment: You are checking the address of the cell, you should check the content.

Comment: @A.S.H.  I updated code with suggestion from another post but still does not work.  The cell that is checked if number seems to be hardcoded.

Comment: This question was about finding the `IsNumeric` keyword and is closed now. For any other question please feel free to open another post. Thanks

Comment: @A.S.H Now around 7,640,000..... and this question ranks as #1-#2 in the several searches I tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer was in the question! There is a function `isNumeric(variable_goes_here)` which will return a true or false e.g.

```
if isNumeric(x) then msgbox("Woop!")
```

will return a true and give you the message box for `x = 45` but will skip if `x = "Not a number"`